# Accessing variables from another require JS module

Tags: magento2, javascript, template, jquery, requirejs

Cannot understand how to organize JS/PHTML cross vars and functions calling for Magento 2 using Require.js.
The standard methods are not working. Made a lot of tries, but no success. Hope somebody help me.

**Task**: get the var value and call function in JS file from the script located in PHTML template

**We have**: requirejs-config.js, modu.js, ask.phtml

**Code**:

requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            modu: "js/modu",
        }
    },
    deps: [
        "js/modu",
    ],
    paths: {
        modu: "js/modu",
    },
};
```

modu.js

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "domReady!"
], function($) {
    "use strict";

    var moduVar = 'ModuVar test var';

    function fromPhtml(x) {
        console.log(x);
    }

});
```

ask.phtml

```
<script>

require([
        'jquery',
        'modu',
        'domReady!'
    ], function($, modu) {

    console.log(modu.moduVar);

    modu.fromPhtml("This is output from ask.phtml");

});

</script>
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually return your data, this works:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "domReady!"
], function($) {
    "use strict";
    var modu = {};
    var moduVar = 'ModuVar test var';

    function fromPhtml(x) {
        console.log(x);
    }

    return modu = {
        moduVar: moduVar,
        fromPhtml: fromPhtml
    };
});
```

In your template/other Js file:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/modu',
    'domReady!'
], function($, modu) {
    console.log(modu.moduVar);
    modu.fromPhtml('This is output from ask.phtml');
});
```

**Result**

[image]

FYI I have changed the paths as I mocked this up quickly.

Comment: Hi @Ben. Can you please look over that? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258551/magento-2-access-ko-observable-variable-into-other-js-file