# Magento 2 : Access ko observable variable into other js file

Tags: magento2, knockout

I want to access ko observable variable from one js file to other js file. I apply some logic using below way. But, it's return undefined.

**kotemplate.js :**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'ko'
], function($,Component,ko) {
    "use strict";
    return Component.extend({
            defaults:{
                temp: ko.observable(0)
            },
            initialize: function () {
                self = this;
                this._super();
            },
            addCustomOptionsVal : function(temp) {
                 this.temp = temp;
                 console.log(this.temp);
            }
    });
});
```

**price-options.js : (In my module js file)**

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "priceUtils",
    "Vendor_Module/js/kotemplate",
    "priceOptions",
    "jquery/ui"
], function($, utils,kotemplate){
    "use strict";
    $.widget("vendormodule.priceOptions", $.mage.priceOptions, {

        /**
         * Custom option change-event handler
         * @param {Event} event
         * @private
         */
        _onOptionChanged: function onOptionChanged(event) {
            var changes,
                option = $(event.target),
                handler = this.options.optionHandlers[option.data('role')];

            option.data('optionContainer', option.closest(this.options.controlContainer));

            if (handler && handler instanceof Function) {
                changes = handler(option, this.options.optionConfig, this);
            } else {
                changes = defaultGetOptionValue(option, this.options.optionConfig,this.options.priceFormatJson);
            }
            $(this.options.priceHolderSelector).trigger('updatePrice', changes);
        }
    });

    /**
     * Custom option preprocessor
     * @param  {jQuery} element
     * @param  {Object} optionsConfig - part of config
     * @return {Object}
     */
    function defaultGetOptionValue(element, optionsConfig,priceFormatJson) {
        var changes = {},
            optionValue = element.val(),
            optionId = utils.findOptionId(element[0]),
            optionName = element.prop('name'),
            optionType = element.prop('type'),
            optionConfig = optionsConfig[optionId],
            optionHash = optionName,
            optionPriceTax = {};

        switch (optionType) {
            case 'text':
            case 'textarea':
                changes[optionHash] = optionValue ? optionConfig.prices : {};
                break;

            case 'radio':
                if (element.is(':checked')) {
                    changes[optionHash] = optionConfig[optionValue] && optionConfig[optionValue].prices || {};
                    var custom_option_title = element.parents('.control').prev().find('span').html();
                    kotemplate.addCustomOptionsVal(custom_option_title); //want to set custom_option_title value in temp variable from here
                }
                break;

            case 'select-one':
                changes[optionHash] = optionConfig[optionValue] && optionConfig[optionValue].prices || {};
                break;

            case 'select-multiple':
                _.each(optionConfig, function (row, optionValueCode) {
                    optionHash = optionName + '##' + optionValueCode;
                    changes[optionHash] = _.contains(optionValue, optionValueCode) ? row.prices : {};
                });
                break;

            case 'checkbox':
                optionHash = optionName + '##' + optionValue;
                changes[optionHash] = element.is(':checked') ? optionConfig[optionValue].prices : {};
                break;

            case 'file':
                // Checking for 'disable' property equal to checking DOMNode with id*="change-"
                changes[optionHash] = optionValue || element.prop('disabled') ? optionConfig.prices : {};
                break;
        }
        window.custom_option_arr = optionListData;
        return changes;
    }

    return $.vendormodule.priceOptions;
});
```

How to get value of kotemplate.temp and set value in that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Quick solution

Change `kotemplate.temp` to `kotemplate.temp()`, when getting the value from a KO observable you need to include the parenthesis. This method is much shorter but isn't quite as easy to figure out for developers not used to UI components.

**Parent File**

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'ko'
], function(Component,ko) {
    "use strict";
    return Component.extend({
        defaults:{
            temp: ko.observable(0)
        }
    });
});
```

**Child File**

```
require([
    'Magento_Theme/js/parent',
], function(parent) {
    parent().temp();
});
```

## More verbose method

This method involves more code but should be easier for new developers to pick up, create your own getter function:

**Parent file**

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'ko'
], function(Component,ko) {
    "use strict";
    return Component.extend({
        defaults:{
            temp: ko.observable(0)
        },

        getTemp: function() {
            return this.temp();
        }
    });
});
```

**Child file**

```
require([
    'Magento_Theme/js/parent',
], function(parent) {
    parent().getTemp();
});
```

## Subscribing to the parent file's observable

If you need to subscribe to the observable for when it changes you can do this:

```
parent().temp.subscribe(function(value) {
    console.log('The new value of temp is' + value);
});
```

To test this I just increased the observable value by 1 every 2 seconds.

```
initialize: function() {
    this._super();
    var self = this;

    window.setInterval(function() {
        var newValue = self.temp() + 1;
        self.temp(newValue);
    }, 2000);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, your solution is not working.

Comment: First, when page load kotemplate.js is call. After on button click, when popup open at that time, other js is called. So, I created ko.observable variable in kotemplate.js file and set value from other js. Then, need to access in kotemplate.js.

Comment: I need to see all your code to help with that, it sounds like you need to subscribe to that variable? The code I provided there does work I've tested it twice so maybe you're changing something?

Comment: Okay. Let me check again.

Comment: please check my updated question. addCustomOptionsVal() function is not a function always this error return when click on custom option radio button.

Comment: I think that's because "kotemplate" is actually "priceOptions" because it's the third argument in define. Try console logging kotemplate and see what you get back.

Comment: I change the sequence in 2nd js file. Now, my custom js is kotemplate. Still, it's return error. kotemplate.addCustomOptionsVal is not a function :(

Comment: You made my day..!!! It's working. Thanks a lot man :)

Comment: Just 1 more question.. Can you please tell me parent().getTemp(); why you used parent as function ?

Comment: To be honest I'm not entirely sure why it's a function, I tried it without the parenthesis and it didn't work. Without looking into it I can only presume the component needs to initialise for you to have access to it's properties. If it works without the parenthesis for you then it should be fine. 

Glad I could help.

Comment: This solution still works, thank you!

Comment: Can we update the component's observable variable in the phtml file?